# How do I throttle Ubuntu One?

Tags: 11.04, ubuntu-one

Ubuntu One sync is using almost all of my CPU resources. How do I control that?

Answer (score 3):

You go to the devices tab of the ubuntu one control panel, there you will find a "limit sync bandwidth usage"

Answer (score 2):

The "Limit File Sync bandwidth usage" option does NOT work in Ubuntu 11.04, and has NOT worked since 10.04.

The best solution I could find is this: http://aangaero.wordpress.com/category/cloud-services/ubuntu-one/